# I need help implementing this UI in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, listview

[I've tried using row inside of column for the title bar and listview.builder for the content of the selected item.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z0k6.png)

[So the code goes like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvL7Z.png)

Comment: hey can you please expand the drop down button to see the code

Comment: can you include as code-snippet

Comment: @YeasinSheikh i can send the code but the comment wont allow, how can i share it?

Comment: https://easyupload.io/ofw1vp this link holds the text file containing code

Comment: can you use pastebin or better try to make it minimal and include on question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a simple code sample for you, try this:

```
  class UserActivities extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserActivities({super.key});

  @override
  State<UserActivities> createState() => _UserActivitiesState();
}

const List<String> list = [
  'All Activity Types',
  'Comment Activity',
  'Post Activity',
  'Interreaction Activity'
];

class _UserActivitiesState extends State<UserActivities> {
  String dropdownValue = list.first;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              const Text('Activities'),
              DropdownButton(
                value: dropdownValue,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                  (value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    );
                  },
                ).toList(),
                onChanged: (String? value) {
                  setState(() {
                    dropdownValue = value!;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          //Spacer(),
          SizedBox(
              height: 400,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                  child: Text(
        // customize this widgets as you want
                    'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black12),
                  ),
                ),
                itemCount: 100,
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The preview:
[image]

Comment: thank you. it solved the problem. however, i still want to implement, the change of the content i.e. lorem ipsum listview builder in this case is set when "All Activity Type" is selected. i want to change the content when the type is "Comment Activity"

Comment: for the changes you want tapping different dropdown options is required multiple lists and your own logic in "onChange" method. but try the basic one and learn step by step.